# Facebook Graph API, error_subcode: 1366063

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post, photo

It's been three days that the Facebook Graph Api fails to publish some of the photos of our users. Only about 1% of the photo fails. This is the error message, but I could not find the subcode anywhere!

```
-responseData: array:1 [
  "error" => array:8 [
    "message" => "Invalid parameter"
    "type" => "OAuthException"
    "code" => 100
    "error_subcode" => 1366063
    "is_transient" => false
    "error_user_title" => "The album is no longer available"
    "error_user_msg" => "Try to create a new album"
    "fbtrace_id" => "DJsbfZeBYQD"
  ]
]
```

Someone has this problem too?
This seems to be an album problem, but I tried to delete the album in witch the photos goes on several profiles, but the graph api always recreates it correctly!!

Thanks guys!!!

EDIT: I'll add some details. 
We use the SDK v4 via composer:

```
"facebook/php-sdk-v4": "~4.0"
```

And we post the photo with FacebookRequest:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
                $session,
                'POST',
                '/me/photos',
                array (
                    'url' => 'photo.jpg',
                    'message' => 'message',
                )
            );
```

Of course we set the $session with the appId and user token.

Comment: What album are you posting to? How?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've added some details in the original question!

Comment: That sounds weird. Sugget you file a bug report, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Ok, it was a bug of Facebook... magically today the problem disappeared, and we posted all the old photos.